# Basic Complex Integration Question on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to find $$\int \dfrac{dz}{(z-1)^3}$$ on the circle $|z|=2$.

I'm pretty new to this, so my instincts were to use Cauchy's theorem for this, namely that the integral of an analytic function on the boundary of a region of this type is zero. However, the function isn't analytic, at $z=1$.

I know that we can modify Cauchy's theorem for when there is only one non analytic point, but I'm pretty sure we can only do that when $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)$ equals zero, and here I don't think it does, as it becomes $$\lim\frac{(z-1)}{(z-1)^3}=\lim \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$$ which isn't zero. So I'm pretty stuck. I know that residue is a thing that might be applicable, but I havent learned it very much.

Can it be done without it, or if residue is needed, how would I do it? Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: The function to be integrated has a nice primitive... You can use it. If you still want to use residues, you compute the Laurent expansion around $1$, which is trivial here.

Comment: Hi! You should see and understand Cauchy's Integral formula and Cauchy's Integral formula for derivatives before trying to compute this integral with Residues Theorem. Theese two formulas I mentioned are very important theorems in complex analysis